# Postgresql change column type from int to UUID

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to change the column type from an `int` to a `uuid`. I am using the following statement

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ALTER COLUMN colA SET DATA TYPE UUID;
```

But I get the error message

```
ERROR:  column "colA" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

I am confused how to use `USING` to do the cast.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can't just cast an int4 to uuid; it'd be an invalid uuid, with only 32 bits set, the high 96 bits being zero.

If you want to generate new UUIDs to replace the integers entirely, and if there are no existing foreign key references to those integers, you can use a fake cast that actually generates new values.

**Do not run this** without a backup of your data. It permanently throws away the old values in `colA`.

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ALTER COLUMN colA SET DATA TYPE UUID USING (uuid_generate_v4());
```

A better approach is usually to *add* a uuid column, then fix up any foreign key references to point to it, and finally drop the original column.

You need the UUID module installed:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

The quotes are important.

Comment: I get "ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist". Is there some add-on that I need?

Comment: `ERROR: default for column "Id" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid
SQL state: 42804` when running the command, i adding a column seams to be the only working option

Comment: @EliyaKonzo Without knowing what you used as the `DEFAULT` I can't possibly offer any suggestions there.

Comment: I never defined it, i had a table using codefirst with int as primary key after realizing npgsql wont create sequence on int, i installed the extension and run the command as you instructed and that is the exact error i got. @CraigRinger

Comment: @konzo Do this: `ALTER TABLE tableA ALTER COLUMN colA DROP DEFAULT, ALTER COLUMN colA TYPE uuid USING (uuid_generate_v4()), ALTER COLUMN colA SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()`

Comment: in current postgresql 10.x I didn't need to add any extension. I did: `ALTER TABLE mail ALTER COLUMN uuid TYPE UUID USING UUID::UUID;` that's it.

Comment: Does anyone have an example or guidance for a case where the primary key is also a foreign key(s)?  Can I use `uuid_generate_v4` to update the foreign key column values from `VARCHAR` to `uuid` as well and expect the same results for transforming IDs as on the primary key?

Answer (score 23):

Just if someone comes across this old topic. I solved the problem by first altering the field into a CHAR type and then into UUID type.

Comment: Can you explain how you do this further?

Comment: It means 
1. You should change type int(bigint) -> varchar(64) 
2. Change type varchar(64) -> uuid
Or adapt it for your case

Answer (score 11):

I was able to convert a column with an `INT` type, configured as an incrementing primary key using the `SERIAL` shorthand, using the following process:

```sql
--  Ensure the UUID extension is installed.
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

--  Dropping and recreating the default column value is required because
--  the default INT value is not compatible with the new column type.
ALTER TABLE table_to_alter ALTER COLUMN table_id DROP DEFAULT, 
ALTER COLUMN table_id SET DATA TYPE UUID USING (uuid_generate_v4()), 
ALTER COLUMN table_id SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

Comment: What's the point of casting the ids to text before overwriting them with new uuids?

Comment: You won't be able to cast directly from an integer to a UUID because the default value for the column won't be compatible with the new type. You can't change the default value to one that *will* be compatible, since a UUID is not compatible with an integer. If you change the type to TEXT first, the default UUID value will be compatible. From there you can safely change the column type to UUID. There might be another way to accomplish this, but it works.

Comment: Can you not simply change them at the same time, `ALTER TABLE table_to_alter
ALTER COLUMN table_id
SET DATA TYPE UUID USING (uuid_generate_v4()),
SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();`?

Comment: Does that actually work? I tried this on my version of Postgres and, barring some syntactic mistake on my part, this wasn't allowed.

Comment: Ah, needs a second `ALTER COLUMN` for the action. (No I had not tried it out). What should work in any case is `ALTER TABLE table_to_alter ALTER COLUMN table_id DROP DEFAULT, ALTER COLUMN table_id SET DATA TYPE UUID USING (uuid_generate_v4()), ALTER COLUMN table_id SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();`. My guess would be that it works even without the `DROP DEFAULT` since it's a single statement.

Comment: Oh wow. I just tried this then and it works perfectly. Great work! Should I amend my answer or do you want to post this as your own answer?

Comment: Feel free to use it in your answer. It seems that the OPs question generally is answered by the `USING` expression. Doing something about defaults is just a supplement.

Answer (score 10):

I had to convert from text to uuid type, and from a Django migration, so after solving this I wrote it up at http://baltaks.com/2015/08/how-to-change-text-fields-to-a-real-uuid-type-for-django-and-postgresql in case that helps anyone. The same techniques would work for an integer to uuid conversion.

Based on a comment, I've added the full solution here:

Django will most likely create a migration for you that looks something like:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0001_auto'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='modelname',
            name='uuid',
            field=models.UUIDField(db_index=True, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

First, put the auto created migration operations into a RunSQL operation as the `state_operations` parameter. This allows you to provide a custom migration, but keep Django informed about what's happened to the database schema.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0001_auto'),
    ]

    operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL(sql_commands, None, [
            migrations.AlterField(
                model_name='modelname',
                name='uuid',
                field=models.UUIDField(db_index=True, unique=True),
            ),
        ]),
    ]
```

Now you'll need to provide some SQL commands for that `sql_commands` variable. I opted to put the sql into a separate file and then load in with the following python code:

```
sql_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '0001.sql')
with open(sql_path, "r") as sqlfile:
    sql_commands = sqlfile.read()
```

Now for the real tricky part, where we actually perform the migration. The basic command you want looks like:

`alter table tablename alter column uuid type uuid using uuid::uuid;`

But the reason we are here is because of indexes. And as I discovered, Django likes to use your migrations to created randomly named indexes on your fields while running tests, so your tests will fail if you just delete and then recreate a fixed name index or two. So the following is sql that will delete one constraint and all indexes on the text field before converting to a uuid field. It also works for multiple tables in one go.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    table_names text[];
    this_table_name text;
    the_constraint_name text;
    index_names record;

BEGIN

SELECT array['table1',
             'table2'
             ]
    INTO table_names;


FOREACH this_table_name IN array table_names
LOOP
    RAISE notice 'migrating table %', this_table_name;

    SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME INTO the_constraint_name
    FROM information_schema.constraint_column_usage
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = current_schema()
        AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('uuid')
        AND TABLE_NAME = this_table_name
    GROUP BY CONSTRAINT_NAME
    HAVING count(*) = 1;
    if the_constraint_name is not NULL then
        RAISE notice 'alter table % drop constraint %',
            this_table_name,
            the_constraint_name;
        execute 'alter table ' || this_table_name
            || ' drop constraint ' || the_constraint_name;
    end if;

    FOR index_names IN
    (SELECT i.relname AS index_name
     FROM pg_class t,
          pg_class i,
          pg_index ix,
          pg_attribute a
     WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid
         AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid
         AND a.attrelid = t.oid
         AND a.attnum = any(ix.indkey)
         AND t.relkind = 'r'
         AND a.attname = 'uuid'
         AND t.relname = this_table_name
     ORDER BY t.relname,
              i.relname)
    LOOP
        RAISE notice 'drop index %', quote_ident(index_names.index_name);
        EXECUTE 'drop index ' || quote_ident(index_names.index_name);
    END LOOP; -- index_names

    RAISE notice 'alter table % alter column uuid type uuid using uuid::uuid;',
        this_table_name;
    execute 'alter table ' || quote_ident(this_table_name)
        || ' alter column uuid type uuid using uuid::uuid;';
    RAISE notice 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX %_uuid ON % (uuid);',
        this_table_name, this_table_name;
    execute 'create unique index ' || this_table_name || '_uuid on '
        || this_table_name || '(uuid);';

END LOOP; -- table_names

END;
$$
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628637/convert-data-on-alterfield-django-migration

Answer (score 9):

I'm bumping to this after a long time, but there is a way to convert your integer column to a UUID with some kind of backwards-compatibility, namely keeping a way to have a reference to your old values, rather than dropping your values.
It comprises of converting your integer value to a hex string and then padding that with necesary zeroes to make up an artificial UUID.

So, assuming your current integer column is named ColA, the following statement would do it (mind the `using` part):

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ALTER COLUMN ColA SET DATA TYPE UUID USING LPAD(TO_HEX(ColA), 32, '0')::UUID;
```

Comment: I'm planning to do something like your solution. But I wonder whether this will significantly increase the chance that newly generated UUIDs conflicting with these converted values?

Comment: Unless you have billions and billions of rows, the chance of conflicts for UUIDs is negligible

Answer (score 6):

In PostgreSQL 9.3 you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE "tableA" ALTER COLUMN "ColA" SET DATA TYPE UUID USING "ColA"::UUID;
```

And cast the type of data to `UUID` and this will avoid the error message.

Comment: ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to uuid

Comment: Worked for me casting varchar(36) to uuid

Comment: This is the correct answer to [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69224546/2943403).

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: I've noticed some comments and answers that try to cast integers to a UUID4.

You **must not cast or force-set uuid values**. They must be generated using functions relating to [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122).

UUIDs must be randomly distributed or they will not work. You cannot cast or enter your own UUIDs as they will not be properly distributed. This can lead to bad actors guessing your sequencing or finding other artifacts or patterns in your UUIDs that will lead them to discover others.

Any answer that converts to char types and then to uuid may lead to these kinds problems.

Follow any answer here that refers to '**uuid_generate_v4**'. Ignore ones that are casting or setting without using the formal functions.

Comment: Good comment, but for some people the lack of randomness is a feature rather than a bug. For instance, we need a UUID for Apple's CallKeep, but don't actually want it to be random.

Comment: This is not a real concern when using ints as IDs and trying to replace one server using int IDs with multiple servers using uuids. In this case you want the type int+uiid as column type, but this type is not available in postgress forcing you to put int into an UIID column or using composite column (and wasting space) with UIID and int, alternative you could try varchar but nobody is going to be happy with varchar ID column. This is of course only an issue needed when supporting legacy IDs.

Answer (score 1):

For changing from `int` column type to `uuid` I want to keep following properties:

- `uuid` must be globally unique
- id in migrated column must be **deterministically** generated, so in case that there are any hard-coded data in migrations, I'm able to reference them even after migration identifier.

## Migration path

### 1) Drop foreign key

...drop all references to `Table1`

```sql
ALTER TABLE "Table2" DROP CONSTRAINT "Foreign_Table2_IdTable1";
```

### 2) migrate int-ids to uuid deterministically

```sql
ALTER TABLE "Table1" ALTER COLUMN "Id" SET DATA TYPE UUID USING DETERMINISTIC_TO_UUID("Id");
ALTER TABLE "Table2" ALTER COLUMN "IdTable1" SET DATA TYPE UUID USING DETERMINISTIC_TO_UUID("IdTable1");
```

**Note:** `DETERMINISTIC_TO_UUID()` needs to be defined, see below!

### 3) add foreign keys back

```sql
ALTER TABLE "Table2" ADD CONSTRAINT "Foreign_Table2_IdTable1" FOREIGN KEY ("IdTable1") REFERENCES "Table1" ("Id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE;
```

## How to deterministically convert UUIDs?

### Simplest way

Function that generates invalid UUID, which are however good-enough for most cases:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DETERMINISTIC_TO_UUID(inputData bigint) RETURNS uuid AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN LPAD(TO_HEX(inputData), 32, '0')::uuid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

### uuid4 variant1 compatible version

I have implemented following two functions:

- `bitstringIdFrom(tableName varchar, id bigint): bit(128)` – generate 128-bitstring for given table name & numeric ID
- `makeUuid4variant1From(bit(128)): uuid` – Generate valid uuid4 from 128-bitstring

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION makeUuid4variant1From(inputData bit(128)) RETURNS uuid AS $$
DECLARE uuid4variant1_mask CONSTANT bit(128) := ~((B'1111'::bit(128) >> 48) | (B'11'::bit(128) >> 64));
    DECLARE uuid4variant1_versionData CONSTANT bit(128) := (4::bit(4)::bit(128) >> 48) | (2::bit(2)::bit(128) >> 64);
    DECLARE uuidInBitString bit(128);
    DECLARE low_bits bit(64);
    DECLARE hi_bits bit(64);
BEGIN
    -- This actually makes valid uuid4 variant1
    -- mask removes bits necesarry for version & variant data
    -- OR operation adds required version & variant data
    uuidInBitString := ("inputdata" & uuid4variant1_mask) | uuid4variant1_versionData;

    -- As PostgreSQL does NOT support working with 128-bit itegers, we need to split it into half
    -- working with bit-strings: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-bitstring.html, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-bitstring.html
    low_bits := (uuidInBitString << 64)::bit(64);
    hi_bits  := (uuidInBitString << 0) ::bit(64);

    RETURN (
            LPAD(TO_HEX(hi_bits::bigint), 16, '0') || LPAD(TO_HEX(low_bits::bigint), 16, '0')
        )::uuid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


-- creates bit-string from given table name & int-ID
-- This uses deterministic hash function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bitstringIdFrom(tableName varchar, id bigint) RETURNS bit(128) AS $$
    DECLARE uuidAsBitString bit(128) := 0::bit(128);
    DECLARE salt text := 'some-secret-text-to-improve-unguessability';
    DECLARE part1 bit(32);
    DECLARE part2 bit(32);
    DECLARE part3 bit(32);
    DECLARE part4 bit(32);
BEGIN
    -- in case someone want to guess migrated uuids
    -- they would need to know this secret & hashing algorithm
    id := id + hashtext(salt);

    -- source: https://hakibenita.com/postgresql-hash-index#hash-function
    part1 := (hashtext(tablename) * id)::bit(32);
    part2 := (hashtext(part1::text) * id)::bit(32);
    part3 := (hashtext(part2::text) * id)::bit(32);
    part4 := (hashtext(part3::text) * id)::bit(32);

    uuidAsBitString := part1::bit(128) | uuidAsBitString;
    uuidAsBitString := uuidAsBitString >> 32;
    uuidAsBitString := part2::bit(128) | uuidAsBitString;
    uuidAsBitString := uuidAsBitString >> 32;

    uuidAsBitString := part3::bit(128) | uuidAsBitString;
    uuidAsBitString := uuidAsBitString >> 32;

    uuidAsBitString := part4::bit(128) | uuidAsBitString;

    RETURN uuidAsBitString;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

## How to achieve real uuid4 randomness?

As when we have been creating new forign key, we have created it with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, you can simply achieve that by:

```sql
UPDATE "Table1" SET "Id" = uuid_generate_v4();
```

... which will automatically update also all foreign keys referenced.

**Note:** This can take a really long time as machine randomness can be depleted quite quickly. Therefore I recommend to use good salt/secret and use deterministic migration path.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a derivative from @pritstift's answer above

here's how I did It, first to convert it to **CHAR**

`ALTER TABLE my_tbl ALTER my_ col TYPE CHARACTER VARYING(10);`

then as @SeinopSys in the accepted answer's comment said

`ALTER TABLE tableA ALTER COLUMN colA DROP DEFAULT, ALTER COLUMN colA TYPE uuid USING (uuid_generate_v4()), ALTER COLUMN colA SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()`

This will first convert the integer column into CHAR column, and then replace the whole column with newly created uuids.
Make sure you have no foreign key relations associated with ID column and you have a backup of your table before implementing it

Answer (score 0):

I am using PostgreSQL through Supabase, and I have this problem too.
cannot cast bigint to uuid.

Above problem happens when I want to change my primary key which is int8 type to uuid type.

To solve the problem, I just change the datatype from int8 -> varchar -> uuid.