# Can't syncdb with UUID field

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to generate a new database with uuid using django and postgresql

I have a model with UUID field like this :

```
 class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser):
     id = models.UUIDField(_('id'), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

When i try to syncdb i got the following error :

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "id" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid
>   HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.

I already try to modify the type by hand doing:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
ALTER TABLE baseuser ALTER COLUMN id SET DATA TYPE UUID USING (uuid_generate_v4());
```

end up with this error:

> ERROR: default for column "Id" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid

I also tried sqlite without success

I just want to generate a new db with uuid, I don't care about existing data.

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342717/postgresql-change-column-type-from-int-to-uuid

Comment: Yes thanks, i finally end up deleting all past migrations and it work.