# Convert data on AlterField django migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a production database and need to keep safe the data. I want to change a Field in model and convert all data inside that database with this change.

Old field

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_name = models.TimeField()
```

Changed field

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_name = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Basically I want to convert the TimeField value (that has a Time object) in minutes.

Example: I have in an object `time(hour=2, minute=0, second=0)` and I want to convert that field value in all database table to `120` when I apply the migrate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Safest way that I always do is:

1. create another field with `field_name_new = models.PositiveIntegerField()`
2. migrate this new field on production db
3. do data migration (convert `field_name` value and move the 
   converted value to field `field_name_new`)
4. change your code so that `field_name_new` is used
5. deploy the step 4
6. delete the field `field_name`
7. migrate the step 6 on production db and deploy it (the step 6)

there is only one bad side: you may loose some data in steps 4 and 5. but you can replicate these data to new field basically

Answer (score 35):

In the past, I've always done this with the help of Djangos RunPython operation. Create a custom migration that handles the following.

1. Change name of field.
2. Add new field of desired type.
3. RunPython to handle the logic of converting from one to the other.
4. Delete old field.

```
def migrate_time_to_positive_int(apps, schema_editor):

    MyModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyModel')

    for mm in MyModel.objects.all():

        field_old_time = mm.field_name_old
        field_new_int = field_old_time.total_seconds() / 60
        mm.field_name = field_new_int 
        mm.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            old_name='field_name',
            new_name='field_name_old',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='field_name',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(migrate_time_to_positive_int),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='field_name_old',
        )
    ]
```

field_name_old.total_seconds() / 60 might need to be adjusted, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is very interesting, I'll try this too. Thanks

Comment: This is a good overview, also you can possibly update this without a for loop in python (which could potentially be very slow). For example, MyModel.objects.all().update(field_name=F('field_name_old')/60)

Comment: Add "migrations.RunPython.noop" that way "migrations.RunPython(migrate_time_to_positive_int, migrations.RunPython.noop)", otherwise in case of downgrade, you will get the error "django.db.migrations.exceptions.IrreversibleError"