# Migrate a PositiveIntegerField to a FloatField

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I have an existing populated database and would like to convert a `PositiveIntegerField` into a `FloatField`. I am considering simply doing a migration:

```
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='mymodel',
        name='field_to_convert',
        field=models.FloatField(
            blank=True,
            help_text='my helpful text',
            null=True),
    ),
```

Where the field is currently defined as:

```
field_to_convert = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    help_text='my helpful text')
```

Will this require a full rewrite of the database column? How well might this conversion scale for larger databases? How might it scale if the vast majority values were `null`? In what circumstances would this conversion fail? This is a backed by a Postgres database if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Will this require a full rewrite of the database column?

No, it won't. I did an experiment with PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite the conversion from integer to float goes well in every case, I also put some values as null to match your situation.

If you have a value `3`, it just will change to `3.0`.

### How might it scale if the vast majority values were null?

Well, since you keep `null=True` in the configuration of your field all null values will remain null, no problem with that. If you remove `null=True` you might need to specify a `default` value.

### In what circumstances would this conversion fail?

Taking an int column and converting it to float (real) should not fail, if you find a bizarre, weird and very special case it would be a very big finding.

### If you have doubts about the migration outcome...

...  you can first take a look into migrations SQL with [sqlmigrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate), and of course, you could backup your database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sqlmigrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate) to check generated sql for your migration.

> $ python manage.py sqlmigrate *app_label* *migration_name*

Keep in mind, that its output depends on the Django version and the database you have in settings. For the setup I had on hand (Django 1.11, Postgres 9.3) for your migration I got:

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Alter field field_to_convert on mymodel
--
ALTER TABLE "myapp_mymodel" DROP CONSTRAINT "myapp_mymodel_field_to_convert_check";
ALTER TABLE "myapp_mymodel" ALTER COLUMN "field_to_convert" TYPE double precision USING "field_to_convert"::double precision;
COMMIT;
```

Which looks good to me both in terms of performance and reliability. I'd say go ahead with the AlterField.

If you want to be extra safe, you can always go: rename field -> create field -> run python -> drop field. This will give you more control over the migration process. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39663476/723891) for details.